# why angular application not able to get HTTP response data?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-httpclient, angular2-observables

Started to learn angular services and DI but stuck trying to get json data from url in a service.
 This is the service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Employees } from '../models/emp';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  url = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e712acd30000029007a34b8';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getEmployees(): Observable<Employees> {
    // make http request to the given url and fetch the contacts
    return this.http.get<Employees>(this.url);
  }

}
```

**Error in console:**

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown
>   Error", url: "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e712acd30000029007a34b8"…}

**Link to stackblitz demo app:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-osuap2

Comment: The problem is the URL, this mocky API uses https, try `url = 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5e712acd30000029007a34b8';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your interface doesn't match your response.

If your API response is

```
{
   "empList": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "emp1", "city": "city1"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "emp2", "city": "city2"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "emp3", "city": "city3"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "emp4", "city": "city4"}
    ]    
}
```

And you are making the following request:

```js
getEmployees(): Observable<Employees> {
  // make http request to the given url and fetch the contacts
  return this.http.get<Employees>(this.url);
}
```

Then your Employees interface needs to match the response:

```js
export interface Employees {
  empList: Employee[];
}

export interface Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  city: string;
}
```

Your mock API url should also be https.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mr9dz4